# Displaying products from database to view by product ctegory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with my project and I am stuck in place now.

I have main index page which contains photos of products. I would like to display this products by category name.

I made ProductDisplayViewModel.cs which contains:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductDisplayViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public uint ProductQuantity { get; set; }
        public int PremiumPoints { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Later i add category name to action link in my View.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Category", new {Name="Pieczywo"})">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/Images/Mainpage/Categories/pieczywo.jpg" alt="CategoryName">
</a>
```

Next i prepeare CategoryController which contains Action Index with parameter string categoryName.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string categoryName)
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            // pobieranie kategorii po nazwie
            var selectedcategory = db.ProductCategories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == categoryName);

            var q = db.Products.Where(x => x.Category.Contains(selectedcategory)).Select(r => new ProductDisplayViewModel()
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                ProductName = r.ProductName,
                ProductDescription = r.ProductDescription,
                ProductPrice = r.PricePerUnit,
                //ProductQuantity = r.Quantity
                PremiumPoints = r.PremiumPoints
            });

            return View(q.ToList());
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Later in other View i am displaying results:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.ViewModels.ProductDisplayViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

<h2>Products by category name</h2>

<br />
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Product name</th>
                <th>Product description</th>
                <th>Price per unit</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Premium points</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                    <td>@item.ProductDescription</td>
                    <td>@item.ProductPrice</td>
                    <td>@item.ProductQuantity</td>
                    <td>@item.PremiumPoints</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br />

</div>
```

My product model:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Category = new List<ProductCategory>();
        OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
        Supliers = new List<Suplier>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; } // nazwa produktu
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; } // opis produktu
    public string ProductImageUrl { get; set; } // url do obrazka produktu
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> Category { get; set; } // kategorie produktu
    public decimal PricePerUnit { get; set; } // cena jednostkowa
    public int PremiumPoints { get; set; } // punkty zniżki za każdy zakupiony produkt
    public uint Quantity { get; set; } // ilość na stanie
    public NutritionalValue NutritionalValues { get; set; } // wartości odżywcze
    public virtual ICollection<Suplier> Supliers { get; set; } // dostawcy produktu
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And my problem is that when i am trying to display my products by my category name i got error:

> The specified type member 'Quantity' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

It happends when my action try pass q.ToList() to my View()

Its problem with this Quantity. I think that my app cant find this category maybe? How to solve this?

I dont know how to handle with this. Please help me :/

Comment: Can you show the definition of your `Product` data model?

Comment: I posted my data model below :)

Comment: Did you add the `Quantity` property to the `Product` model yourself?

Comment: I was Seeded() my database using Seed() method and migrations. The products was generated. They have all fields like quantity. Yes i do this my self.

Comment: Verify if your database has Quantity field

Comment: Uuu you are right. I dont have quantity field in my Product table :O How to create this?

Comment: Why Code First didn;t generated Quantity field which is uint? Can i update my database?

Comment: I generate missing column Quantity using migrations but i have other problem now. Unable to create a constant value of type 'SklepInternetowy.Models.ProductCategory'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.